# How to test that Flask is using test_client rather than client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pytest

I'm using Pytest fixtures with Flask. My application is instantiated using an application factory.

```
#conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app(request):
    '''Session-wide test application'''
    app = create_app('testing')
    app.client = app.test_client()
    app_context = app.app_context()
    app_context.push()


    def teardown():
        app_context.pop()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return app
```

I wanted to verify that the app created by my fixture uses [Flask's built-in test_client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/), so I wrote a test:

```
#test_basics.py

def test_app_client_is_testing(app):
    assert app.client() == app.test_client()
```

When I run this test, I get: `TypeError: 'FlaskClient' object is not callable`

What am I doing wrong?

Is the test incorrect, or is the fixture incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app.client` is already an instance, you shouldn't call it again.  Ultimately, this test makes no sense.  Of course client is a test client, that's how you just created it in the fixture.  Also, the clients will never be equal, they are different instances.

```
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

assert app.client == app.test_client()  # different instances, never true
assert isinstance(app.client, app.test_client_class or FlaskClient)  # still pointless, but correct
```

---

What you probably want is two fixtures: `app` and `client`, rather than creating a client on the app.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture
def app():
    a = create_app('testing')
    a.testing = True

    with a.app_context():
        yield a

@pytest.yield_fixture
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        yield c

from flask.testing import FlaskClient

def test_app_client_is_client(app, client):
    # why?
    assert isinstance(client, app.test_client_class or FlaskClient)
```